# How to get feature importance of RF in scala 2.10, using Spark 2.1.1?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning

I'm trying to get feature importance from a Random Forest Regressor in Spark MLib. The problem is that I train using `Pipeline` object, and I don't know how to cast such object to a `RandomForestRegressorModel` to get `featureImportance`.

The interesting part of my code is the following

```
val rf = new RandomForestRegressor().
        setLabelCol( "label" ).
        setFeaturesCol( "features" ).
        setNumTrees( numTrees ).
        setFeatureSubsetStrategy( featureSubsetStrategy ).
        setImpurity( impurity ).
        setMaxDepth( maxDepth ).
        setMaxBins( maxBins ).
        setMaxMemoryInMB( maxMemoryInMB )
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(rf))
var model = pipeline.fit( trainingDataCached )
// GET FEATURE IMPORTANCE
val featImp = model.featureImportance
```

What am I missing?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Could that be the right answer?

```
val featImp = model
              .asInstanceOf[RandomForestRegressionModel]
              .featureImportances
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could that be the right answer?

Almost.

```
model
  .stages
  .head
  .asInstanceOf[RandomForestRegressionModel]
  .featureImportances
```

Answer (score 0):

val rfModel = model.stages(2).asInstanceOf[RandomForestClassificationModel]
println("Learned classification forest model:\n" + rfModel.toDebugString)

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/ml-ensembles.html